# Same screen to edit and display

Tags: information-design, information-retrieval

I'm building an infirmary application in which after you log in  and select a patient, you are shown their info on one side with a new visit form on the other side .

I want  to be able to view patient history when one clicks on visit from the history section circled below.

My question is ,should upon clicking , it populate the visit entry form on the right or open up another form to view the information.
For some reason I feel uncomfortable with using the same visual to both enter information and view historical information.
What is the recommended practice for such a case
[image]

Comment: What platforms is this for? Desktop? Tablet? Should each/most screen be printable on paper? I'd probably look at more of a scrolling interface.

Comment: It's for desktop . No we don't need all the screens to be printable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest running a study on what medical staff do when checking on a patient. I would be prepared to bet that the first thing they do is check on the patient's history before making their own examination and finally adding their own notes.

If this *is* the case then you probably want to display a scrollable history (starting with the most recent entry) on the side where you currently have the form and adding a button adds a new empty entry at the top when it's required.

Comment: Yes it's definitely the case, however the history would be all the fields from the visit form filled in, that would be a lot of information to squeeze in , where would you recommend putting it? On top of the current form?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the visit history, why are you showing it in a form? would they be able to edit it as it has a save button? If not, the summary could be shown in a tool tip and user can click on edit history on the circled table to edit besides the view link. that is action on demand.